# Permission denied while writing files

Tags: jboss

We have 4 RHEL server's And JBoss 7.x installed in it. All 4 server's share common mount point where application write file into that mount point.

```
$df -kh 
x.x.x.x:/dir_1/dir_2 
                       97G   23G   70G  25% /dir_1/dir_2
```

There are sub directories created under `/dir_1/dir_2`.

Now, if application running on server 1 already copied a file into `/dir_1/dir_2/dir_3` and application server 2 has to overwrite same file into `/dir_1/dir_2/dir_3` then I get below exception

```
11:26:56,699 ERROR [NP_APP_AL] (Thread-1374856) |||null : MMDispatcher : send(message): java.io.FileNotFoundException:  /dir_1/dir_2/dir_3/RANGODADHI CHEMICAL PVT LTD.pdf (Permission denied)
```

All JBoss instances are running under same user in all server's but they are assigned to different groups.

Regards,
Jay

Comment: I assume the file sharing is happening using NFS?  Are the user id numbers the same for the user on all machines (hint "id username" from the prompt) and what are the directory permissions (ls -ld /dir_1/dir_2)?  I'm guessing that the user is a different UID on one machine vs another or you have uid squashing in your NFS options.

Comment: Yeah, so in NFS, user permissions are by id numbers, not names.  Unless you had impeccable discipline when creating the hosts, the user you're using is probably a different id number on different hosts (they need to be the same).  Groups don't matter so much probably.

Comment: Yes, Files sharing use NFS. All 4 servers have common user
 Here are the permission set in all 4 servers. S1, S2,S3,S4 are servers.     

 S1 : drwxrwxrwx. 3     502     502  667648 Sep  3 15:21 dir_name                      
 S2 : drwxrwxrwx. 3     lgadmin lgadmin  667648 Sep  3 15:21 dir_name                
 S3 : drwxrwxrwx. 3     lgadmin dba      667648 Sep  3 15:21 dir_name           
 S4 : drwxrwxrwx. 3     502 hlsmh    667648 Sep  3 15:21 dir_name

Comment: Yes, the used is assigned with different id & group in each server

Comment: See how two of those show user lgadmin and two show user id 502?  They should all be the same, no?  The user you created has different id numbers on different servers.  There are a bunch of ways to fix this, but the short answer is that the user needs to have the same id number on all machines.

Comment: The problem with having differing numbers is that things created by a process will get weirdo ownerships.  You can squash this in NFS with a mount option (sorta) or you can try playing with a setuid directory to force things to be created by a specific user.

Comment: When I try to change ownership of directory from 502 to lgadmin, on the other server which has lgadmin as owner automatically changes. I am not sure how ownership changes.

Comment: Do you think user "lgadmin" if assigned to common group will solve the problem ?

Comment: Again, under the covers NFS knows nothing about names, only numbers.  If you fix the name on one machine, it'll break on the other because the numbers don't match.  Really you want those to match or you'll be fighting weird permission bugs forever.

Comment: Ok, I will try to have common uid on all servers :)